# Use regular expressions to search for a number + " in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to compile a Regular Expression in Python to search for these values `values_list = ['4.7"', '5.1"', '5.5"']`.

This code can't find 5.1" at all:

`regex = re.compile(r'\b(' + '5.1"' + r')\b')`

`regex.findall('5.1"')`

Comment: What's the deal with the single double-quote inside the single quotes?

Comment: You mean the inch marks?

Comment: @kindall yes, inches.

Comment: Also beware that the dot in `5.1` will mean "any character" in a regex, so your regex will match stuff like `5x1`.  You might want to change your regex to `5\.1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last word boundary `\b` is what failing the regex match. Modify the pattern to:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b(' + '5.1"' + r')')
```

and it'll work.

From the [*docs*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

> The metacharacter \b is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign.
>   It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match
>   is zero-length.
>
> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:
>
> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a
>     word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last
>     character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string,
>     where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Pay close attention to the second bullet point.